# what is the top most container in Android?

Tags: android

Hi if you look into java the top most container could be "window" or "JFrame" where we will be laying out all the rest of the gui components. In Android for every activity we will have a layout defined in xml to use with tthis activity. so when this activity is loaded it loads the associated Layout. So where is this layout drawn. I mean first will it create a default window and it starts drawing the layout on it or how this happens?

Comment: It is View check for reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Comment: Thank you. I found that window is the topmost container which is a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume following is your xml layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/golden_gate" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

        android:padding="12dip"

        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"

        android:text="Golden Gate" />

</FrameLayout>
```

for this xml following view hierarchy would be created:

[image]

The `DecorView` till current android version is actually a `FrameLayout`

This info is taken from Roman Guy blog, check out [this link](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/) for more info..

Comment: in the diagram the top most container is PhoneWindow$DecorView. So what is that PhoneWindow. is the Phones desktop or our application creates one and puts the layout in it. Why i am asking this is in java Layouts are logical . they dont have graphical representation. Here it seems contrary. Here i think layout bu itself is a container  like "window" in java. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily discover it by using Hierarchy Viewer (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) or debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that an activity's content (that you set with `setContentView`) is embedded in a `FrameLayout` that you can access like this:

```
View root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Answer (score 0):

hierarchy-viewer is deprecated in standalone, use [monitor](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html)

Comment: Thank you for this. It is so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The top most container is an internal class `DecorView` which is an extension of `FrameLayout`. You may find some info about it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#PhoneWindow.DecorView)